# How to load playerdata correctly and avoid it from getting the old data

Tags: java, mysql, database, bukkit

I have a problem with bungeecord server network.

Basicly the problem I have as stated in the title when I load playerdata from MySQL database it loads the old data instead of new playerdata that was saved on `PlayerQuitEvent`(`PlayerKickEvent`) and then reloaded almost instantly on `PlayerJoinEvent` in another server.

Here are the steps you can reproduce the problem:

- Setup bungeecord network with 2 servers and SQL methods:
- on `PlayerQuitEvent`(Player switch to another server) store some data into MySQL database(Example: Rank: VIP)

**PROBLEM: SINCE THE DATA DOESN'T UPDATE INSTANTLY IT CAUSES IT TO LOAD OLD DATA FROM BEFORE PLAYER QUIT EVENT**

- on `PlayerJoinEvent`(Player switched to another server) load the data that was stored on PlayerQuitEvent

My code:
Save method:

```
public void saveFields(String uuid, Map<String, String> fields) {
    for (final String s : fields.keySet()) {
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("uuid")) continue;
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) continue;
        createColumn(database + "_data", s);
        sendUpdateQuery("UPDATE " + database + "_data SET " + s + "='" + fields.get(s) + "' WHERE uuid='" + uuid + "'");
    }
}
```

Load method:

```
public Map<String, String> getFields(String uuid) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    try {
        st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + database + "_data WHERE uuid=?");
        st.setString(1, uuid);
        rs = st.executeQuery();
        for (String colum : getColumns(rs)) {
            rs.first();
            if (rs.getRow() != 0) {
                map.put(colum, rs.getString(colum));
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeResources(rs, st);
    }
    closeResources(rs, st);
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is known as the race condition. [MySQL is a bad database and therefore has this problem.](http://grimoire.ca/mysql/choose-something-else) To workaround it, you have to query with a reasonable relay in the second event when the player relogs, or force the player to wait before relogging (which is an approach taken by minigame proxy servers), but it is the most effective to ditch MySQL and use a proper database.

Comment: PostgreSQL? MongoDB? Just look up a few definitive go-tos on wikipedia and do your homework, each of them have their own strengths.